# Problema con las url de laravel (rutas)

Tags: php, laravel, url, rutas, laravel-6

tengo varias rutas de la siguiente forma

```
Route::get('/{slug}','EventoController@mostrar')->name('verevento');
Route::get('/{slug}','ActividadController@mostrar')->name('veractividad');
```

en las vistas las llamó de la siguiente manera

```
<a href="{{route('verevento', ['slug' => $evento['slugEvento']])}}">
<a href="{{route('veractividad', ['slug' => $evento['slugActividad']])}}">
```

el problema es que causan conflicto al ser iguales (/{slug})

hay alguna forma de arreglar eso? sin la necesidad de agregar (actividad/{slug}, evento/{slug})
trate agregando un parámetro para distinguirlas en un controlador diferente y dependiendo del tipo manda a llamar a la ruta que es pero sale el mismo error

existe alguna forma de hacer un return tipo

```
return view('eventoDetalle')->with(['act' => $act])->with(['img' => $img]);
```

junto con un redirect para así pasarle el slug cómo parámetro en una vista diferente?
o no se que otras opciones haya.

Comment: Abre el log de errores de Laravel ahi se grabó el fallo exacto, edita tu pregunta y agrega dicho mensaje

Comment: @Aprendiz no me genero ningún log, el ultimo que tengo es del día 9

Comment: Es raro que un error 500 no se haya grabado, en fin checa si lo que Shaz te propone te ayuda

Comment: @Aprendiz ya me dio el log de hoy

Answer (score 2):

**Me atrevo a escribir esta respuesta sin conocer el error registrado en el Log, pero, de ser necesario, eliminaré esta respuesta posteriormente.**

Las dos rutas son «conflictivas», por así decirlo, puesto que en cierta forma es la misma ruta, pero en una el parámetro `slug` es opcional y en la otra es obligatorio, adicional a esto, están en el raíz de la URL, lo cual puede potencialmente traer algún otro problema.

Lo más probable, es que Laravel esté intentando usar una de las dos «siempre», esto dependiendo del orden de estas en el archivo de rutas (asumiendo que sea web.php), y al acceder a dicha ruta, no esté recibiendo alguna información en el Request que sea necesaria.

---

En pocas palabras, si la url es `mipagina.com/nueva-publicacion`, vemos que el patrón encaja en ambas rutas, por lo cual Laravel ingresará a la primera que esté listada en el archivo de rutas.

---

Para resolver este inconveniente, lo más sencillo sería reorganizar la estructura de las dos rutas, porque no veo coherente que sean iguales, Laravel no es «tan inteligente» como para determinar que dos rutas iguales van a controladores distintos.

```
Route::get('/{slug?}','actividadController@show')->name('veractividad');

Route::get('/evento/{slug}','EventoController@show')->name('vistaEvento');
```

En caso que definitivamente no puedas cambiar su estructura, tendríamos que evaluar otras opciones.

Comment: efectivamente así se soluciona, pero no quiero agregar /evento, intente cambiando el nombre de la variable pero parece que tampoco funciona, por ahora voy a dejar la url así  /actividad-nueva-publicacion.