# duda controladores laravel

Tags: php, laravel, funciones, url, controller

tengo un problema; tengo un case con 4 diferentes opciones. quiero que los 4 apunten a un mismo método, dependiendo del case, se ejecuta una acción diferente.

```
$nombredelafuncion;
public function redireccionar($tipo, $slug) {
        switch ($tipo) {
            case '1':
                return redirect()->route('mostrar', ['slug' => $slug]);
                $nombredelafuncion = 'evento';

            break;
            case '2':
                return redirect()->route('mostrar', ['slug' => $slug]);
                $nombredelafuncion = 'actividad';
            break;
            case '3':
                return redirect()->route('mostrar', ['slug' => $slug]);
            break;
            case '4':
                 return redirect()->route('mostrar', ['slug' => $slug]);
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
    public function mostrar ($slug) {
      //aqui se ejecuta evento o actvidad
      '$nombredelafuncion'($slug);
    }
public function evento($slug =''){
        try {
            $act = Common::consultar('http://apicluby.frb.io/slugObtenerEvento/'.$slug);
            $img = Common::consultar('http://apicluby.frb.io/slugEventoImagenes/'.$slug);
            return view('evento')->with(['act' => $act])->with(['img' => $img]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            echo "Exception:".$e;
            return abort(404);
        }
    }
public function actividad($slug =''){
        try {
            $act = Common::consultar('http://apicluby.frb.io/slugObtenerEvento/'.$slug);
            return view('actividad')->with(['act' => $act]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            echo "Exception:".$e;
            return abort(404);
        }
    }
```

no se si me expliqué, es posible mandar a llamar a una funciona dependiendo del case, uso el redirect porque necesito que la url sea del tipo /{slug}

```
Route::get('/{tipo}{slug}','UrlController@redireccionar')->name('redireccionar');
Route::get('/{slug}','UrlController@mostrar')->name('mostrar');
```

la primera ruta es llama desde una vista en un href, el propósito de la segunda ruta es llamar a la vista y datos correctos.
Espero me puedan ayudar y entender mi problema no se que tan bien me expliqué.

Comment: Al menos yo no entiendo lo que tratas de preguntar, considera pasarte por aquí

Comment: @BetaM https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336576/problema-con-las-url-de-laravel-rutas?noredirect=1#comment610528_336576

Comment: @BetaM quiero saber como puedo resolver eso, o a lo mejor existe una forma algo asi return redirect()->route('mostrar', ['slug' => $slug])->view('eventoDetalle')->with(['act' => $act])->with(['img' => $img]);